# VBA VLookup cells on different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that checks if two cells on two different worksheets are the same. And, if they are the same, uses VLOOKUP to find the difference between assigned values for those cells (which are in a different column)

This is what I have written so far, and I keep getting the error message

> Object doesn't support this property or method

and can not figure out why. Can anyone give input? Thanks!

```
Sub testing()

Product = Range("A2:A506")
Set myrange = Worksheets("open_prices").Range("A2:D506")
Set myrange2 = Worksheets("close_prices").Range("A2:B506")

Dim popen As Integer
Dim pclose As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each Cell In Workbooks("TDO VBA Test.xlsx")
    If Worksheets("open_prices").Range("A2:A506") = Worksheets("close_prices").Range("A2:A506") Then
            popen = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Product, myrange, 4, False)
            pclose = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Product, myrange2, 2, False)
            result = popen - pclose
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you intending with `For Each Cell In Workbooks("TDO VBA Test.xlsx")`?

Comment: because the two cells that I am trying to compare are in different worksheets of the same workbook

Comment: @jsotola It will be the `For` that fails - I'm not sure what the default object within a `Workbook` will be, but I doubt if it can be iterated over.

Comment: @ YowE3K do you know how I might compare two cells and perform the subtraction if the cells are identical?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this only if a cell in "open_prices" (say cell A56) is the same as the equivalent cell in "close_prices" (i.e. cell A56), or are you trying to first find the location within "close_prices" of that same value (i.e. maybe in cell A92) and then do the calc?

Comment: @YowE3K the second-- trying to first find the location of, for ex cell A2 in open_prices, in close_prices, and then do the calc.

Comment: the _for each_ statement means this: `for each item in collection_of_items do something with the item`  ... so you want `for each cell in collection_of_cells ...`  .... which is `for each cell in range ...`     ....  now, workbook is not a collection.  ... workbook.worksheets is a collection of worksheets  ...... what is it that you want `Cell` to represent in the `For each ..` statement?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that this is what you are trying to do, i.e. iterate over each cell in one sheet's A2:A506 and see if the value is in the other sheet and, if it is, do the calculation.

```
Sub testing()

    Dim popen As Integer
    Dim pclose As Integer
    Dim result As Integer ' Are you sure these are integers?  Usually prices will be Double

    Dim VLookupResult As Variant
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Worksheets("open_prices").Range("A2:A506").Cells
        popen = cel.Offset(0, 3).Value
        VLookupResult = Application.VLookup(cel.Value, Worksheets("close_prices").Range("A2:B506"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(VLookupResult) Then
            pclose = VLookupResult
            result = popen - pclose
            ' You will need to decide what to do with this "result" now
            ' that it has been calculated
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much!! so if I'm doing this correctly I should have 505 calculations...and what I want to do is find the largest result out of all the calculations... do you know how I would do this?

Comment: @maddie Yes, start with a variable whose value is set to 0.  Each time `result` is calculated, test whether `result` is greater than it and, if it is, set the variable to the value of `result`.  When your loop is finished that variable will contain the largest value of `result` encountered.  If it doesn't work once you have tried to code it, raise a new question showing what you tried.

Comment: P.S. @maddie Things to think about before you code it: (a) Are you after the largest result (i.e. where the price has dropped the most between open and close), or the smallest (i.e. where the price has increased the most)? (b) Are you after the largest/smallest absolute difference, or the largest/smallest percentage difference, i.e. do you want to know that 10 has decreased by 9 to 1, or that 1011 has decreased by 10 to 1001?  (c) Are you trying to find out the largest/smallest difference, or the item that had that difference?

Comment: @ YowE3K thanks for your help

This is what I coded, and I am still getting the same value for result, which is not the largest value
result = ((VLookupResult - popen) / popen) * 100


Dim x As Double
x = 0

    If Abs(result) > x Then
        x = result
    End If

Next Cell

I am trying to find the largest percentage difference(Abs value), as well as the item that had that difference. I hope this is clear. thanks again!

Comment: @maddie Please raise another question - it's too hard to read code in comments.  (I suspect it is just a case of moving the `x=0` before the loop [it looks like you have it inside the loop there], but it is going to be more useful for future readers if this is its own question.)